# How to avoid browser popup blocker?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsx

```
async payWithPaypal(context, id) {
  context.commit("set_busy", { data: true }, { root: true });

  var response = await ApiService.PAY_WITH_PAYPAL(id);

  if (response.code == 200 && response.data.success) {
      var invoice = response.data.invoice;
      AlertUtil.SHOW_SUCCESS_ALERT("Erledigt!");
      context.commit("updateInvoice", invoice);
      window.open(response.data.redirectUri, "_blank");
  } else {
      AlertUtil.SHOW_SUCCESS_ALERT(response.data.message);
  }

  context.commit("set_busy", { data: false }, { root: true });
},
```

As you can see above, I'd like to open new window when the response is successful.
But the browser popup blocker doesn't allow new window to open.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately it's an education thing and will be down to the individual user allowing this popup. Even then they may not want to!

Comment: Thanks you for response. But it doesn't help me anymore. for example, when I click this <a href="..." target="_blank">, new window opens without any problem. Right?
I want to implement my code simply.

Comment: If you'll work around my pop-up blocker, I'll navigate away from your site, and will never return again, I suppose many other visitors will take this same action. It's my browser, an arbitrary web page should not have any power to decide what I want to allow in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the asynchronous operation, the browser will block it for security reasons. Simulating form submission can solve such problems。

```js
   const openWindow = (url) => {
      let form = document.createElement('form');
      form.action = url;
      form.target = '_blank';
      form.method = 'GET';
      document.body.appendChild(form);
      form.submit();
      // clear
      document.body.removeChild(form);
      form = null;
    }
    openWindow('https://www.example.com');
```